# Python 3 webscraping issue (concerning JS)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm quite stuck trying to scrape a website (using Python/Selenium), that has partially JS-constructed links and stuff in it. In my case, the link I want to get looks like this: http://www.somesite.de/blah/{{link_ID}}

Since one cannot simply scrape this URL directly, my Python-code is as follows:

```
def URL_from_JS (URL):
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\###\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe')
    driver.get(URL)

    link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="Zum Expose"]')
    new_URL = link.get_attribute('href')
    print(new_URL)      #for testing reasons
    driver.close()
    return new_URL
```

This works as intended, however the JS-code is apparently not executed, because the result is exactly as written above (i.e. http://www.somesite.de/blah/{{link_ID}} ). Waiting für the element to become visible has led to nothing but Timeout Errors. The {{link_ID}} references a variable used in some external .js file, which is imported some line lines above in the HTML-code.

Do I have to execute that imported Javascript code manually? I have absolutely no clue why my code isn't working as intended...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How do you send string from `JS` file to `Python` code?

Comment: Don't really understand your question: I don't send strings vom JS to Python. Most likely the JS code will be executed in Python using driver.execute_script, but in my understanding of how Selenium works, this should actually be unnecessary.

Comment: ok.... Where `{{link_ID}}` comes from? Provide `HTML` code sample with link that contain `href="http://www.somesite.de/blah/{{link_ID}}"`

Comment: Here you go: http://www.immobilienscout24.de/neubau/formart/altoh-na-hamburg.html
Edit: the respected linkadress is http://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/87513140 (the first apartment to be bought in this building)

Answer (score 0):

When I manually browse through the site, it opens the link in a new tab. PhantomJS doesn't support tabs

You can try the same with webdriver firefox, simulate click on the first link, switch to the second tab and parse content

If you are able to see the element but python doesn't recognize, then it could an issue with frames, there could be iframes in body tag in which we have the required element and python is searching in the parent frame

You will have to identify the name of the frame and do

driver.switch_to.frame("<>")

Then do a click on the control

hth

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Basically, we have the same problem here: the link element we need to click() in order to open the new window won't show up, it just never becomes visible/clickable. If you just let the driver find the element, then click it, Python throws a non-visible exception, if you implement a wait, you get a timeout exception. Reason is probably because the JS constructing the ending part of the link is never executed.

Comment: If you are able to see the element but python doesn't recognize, then it could an issue with frames, there could be iframes in body tag in which we have the required element and python is searching in the parent frame

You will have to identify the name of the frame and do 

driver.switch_to.frame("<<framename>>")

Then do a click on the control

hth

Comment: This is plausible, but unfortunatley not the case. A quick search in the sourcecode for "frame"/"frameset"/"iframe" did'nt return any hits.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
I did some checks with other webdrivers (FF, Chrome, Phantom): all failed with the very same exception (element not visible) resp. Timeout exception.
Next, I tried to auto-click some other links - this failed, too. I figured out that all these links had some Script in them, because with "hardcoded" links in html my code worked as intended. So I inspected my site with JS disabled in my normal Firefox session, and all those links and stuff were indeed invisible (and therefor not clickable).

By now, I'm 100% sure that I can specify my question/issue:
*something completely prevents Selenium from executing my page's Javascript*; thus, my code doesn't work. Does someone have any idea what might cause this problem?